# Curl to Axios in Node.js - Problem with implementing working curl request with provided certificates - ECONNRESET / Socket hang up error

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to implement working curl request in Axios (Node.js) but with no success.

Working curl request looks like this (I can't share exact request as API is private):

`curl --cacert server.pem --cert client.pem:123password456 -i -H "accept:application/json" -H "content-Type:application/json" "https://example.endpoint.com/"`

So I have these two files, server certificate `server.pem` and client certificate `client.pem` with password `123password456`. When I run this curl request, I get successful response (200 OK). However, that is not the case with my Axios implementation in Node.
My axios request in node looks like this:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./client.pem"),
    passphrase: "123password456",
    ca: fs.readFileSync("./server.pem"),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    httpsAgent: httpsAgent
});

// Error on following line called in async function
let response = await axiosInstance.get("https://example.endpoint.com/");
```

When I run the code above in Node, it instantly throws Axios error:

```
Error: socket hang up\n at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)...
Error object:
{
  code:'ECONNRESET'
  message:'socket hang up'
  isAxiosError:true
  ...
}
```

I have tried it with various edits (for example not using axios instance and using only axios object). Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve issue myself. After inspecting certificate files I found out that the provided client certificate file `client.pem` contained both client certificate and private key. Https agent created with https module requires private key to be specified separately as `key`, modified `httpsAgent` should look like this:

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./client.pem"),
    key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
    passphrase: "123password456",
    ca: fs.readFileSync("./server.pem"),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
```